# What would a cold-adapted knight wear (at Pluto temperatures)?

Tags: society, armors

This is a sequel to my previous question, involving the humanoids on Pluto. Before I ask my question, I want to provide a little context.

Basically, they have a society similar to Europe during the Middle Ages, which means that it has a feudal system. The main focus of the story are the knights, who are considered warriors of their society.

Normally, knights wear chain mail and steel plates, but those don’t provide protection against the cold.

My question is, what would a cold-adapted knight wear to protect themselves?

Comment: How do they breath in Pluto's atmosphere in the first place?

Comment: wear gambeson or other padding inside the plate armor cover it with thick surcoat and follow with cloak or cape, this usually the attire for heavy plate knight in colder region.

Comment: When you say "cold-adapted", how adapted are they? Can they stand outside on Pluto's surface naked for any amount of time? Would they be fine on Earth through an Arctic winter? We need to know how much protection they need from the elements beyond their own adaptations.

Answer (score 6):

**They still wear the armour, but they wear it over paper suits**

If I remember from your previous question, you're after an environment similar to the Barsoom series where we handwave some of the practicalities of living on other planets where the environment is inhospitable and deal with elements of the atmosphere and position in the solar system as if they were merely the most extreme conditions Earth could summon. If that is the case, then read on. If not, clarify in your question and I'll delete this answer as for the record, NO human could survive on Pluto AT ALL without sophisticated life support systems that would make a suit of armour completely obsolete in terms of protection. Also, I'm assuming here that when you say a society similar to the Middle Ages, you also mean a tech level similar to the Middle Ages.

That stipulated, we can move on to say that your Medieval Knights of Pluto (MKPs), even though they are going to need protection from the cold, they are also going to need protection from those trying to kill them. That was the whole point of the armour back in the day; it was intended as protection against enemies in combat, not against the elements. Knights didn't go into combat wearing ONLY the suit of armour, they wore climate appropriate clothing underneath that too. The thing is, I'm assuming here that Pluto in a Barsoom style environment is still VERY cold, and things like wool are hard to come by because keeping animals on the surface is all but impossible in great numbers.

So; you need something plant based that is a great insulator, and I give you wood, or more to the point, paper. Why? Because it's very high in cellulose, which is a fantastic insulator of both electricity and heat. Make a suit out of thick, tear resistant paper and your knight stands a far better chance of not being killed by the cold as he goes out to meet the people who want to also try to kill him. So, you put your suit of armour over the top of that and you protect from swords as well. Also, the paper (assuming you don't make it to be like cardboard) will also protect your knight to at least some degree from chafing in the suit.

How do I know this works? Because it's a known technique [used by homeless people today](https://www.wikihow.com/Stay-Warm-on-Cold-Winter-Nights-if-You-are-Homeless). Having an insulating layer of paper around you is often the difference between life and death in cold winter environments if you're on the street. In your Barsoom-esque Pluto environment, you MKPs are going to want to employ a similar technique while in the field fighting for their lords.

Comment: Paper is also absorbent, which might be helpful.

Comment: [paper armor](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/mythbusters/images/7/75/Kari-Byron-attack-armor.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/340?cb=20160507211815) also exist historically in china too

Comment: Thank you Tim. 
I love that idea.

Comment: Anecdotal: My dad (a farmer) used to wrap his feet in old paper (from the news paper) in addition to his woolen socks, when he had to work outside in winter in rubber boots, as his rubber boots (plain rubber boots, nothing specialized for cold weather) were not insulating. Location is central Europe: generally mild, yet cold spells in winter can be cold. I guess in Scandinavia, they have warmer rubber boots for farm work in winter.